# not getting the right numer of up and downvotes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a problem with my SQL statement. I have a jQuery upvote plugin which saves true and false values in my database. If the user press upvote it will save true in upvote volume, if the user press down vote it will save true in down vote column and if the user press downvote on already upvoted topic it will save true in downvote column and false in upvote column. I know it's a bit confusing. Moreover voting on a new topic will result in saving 0 in the opposite column you clicked. The problem is

[image] [image]

```
Fig 1: when clicked up  |Fig 2: when clicked down
```

[image]

But when I refresh the page the number remains 0

My SQL query:

```
SELECT
SUM(
    IF(Upvote='true' AND Downvote='false',1,
        IF(upvote='false' AND Downvote='true',-1,
            IF(Upvote='false' AND Downvote='false',-1,
                IF(Downvote='false',1,
                    IF(Downvote='true' AND (Upvote='0' OR Upvote=false),-1,0)
                )
            )
        )
    )) as `votes`
```

FROM Ratings
WHERE TopicD = :current

Comment: I suggest you to change your db schema to store total sum of all upvotes/downvotes because of performance reasons

Comment: @IlyaBursov can you guide me how?

Comment: How do you associate the votes to a user?

Comment: @samscoot no, I'm writing book on another topic right now

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix  currently not just sorting it with topic id

Comment: Why do you have `Upvote='false' AND Downvote='false'` set to -1? Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: keep a column in your table as 'vote' and increment it wen you hit up vote and decrement when you do down vote

Comment: How will you know who voted on what?  I could then upvote 1m times and you would never know.  It's not something you can "add" on because it requires a different DB structure for a many to many relationship.

Comment: @janith1024 what if the user undo his vote by clicking the same button

Comment: @samscoot he can't undo his vote, because you have no idea who voted.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix i understand that but right know I am struggling with the basics though

Comment: No, your building something that will not work in the future and who's structure will also likely not work, in other words you wasting you time. IMO

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix so what should be the structure

Comment: @samscoot it should handle in your client side for current session

Comment: On a sidenote: You say you sometimes store false, sometimes true, sometimes 0 and in your query there is `Upvote='0' OR Upvote=false`. What datatype is this column? `Upvote=false` suggests a boolean; `Upvote='0'` suggests a string. Stay consistent and use data types correctly. Then this is a very strange set of possible values. A thing that can either be true or false or zero? That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to properly record votes you need 3 pieces of information,

1. what topic was voted on.
2. who did the voting.
3. if the vote was up or down

This requires a Many to Many relationship.  Many Users may vote on Many topics. It helps to say it like that, see if it makes sense.

For example, we cant say, that many users can vote on one topic. Because I assume you plan to have more then one topic.  And we cant say that many topics would be voted on by 1 user.  Neither of those make much sense.

A many to many relationship takes 3 tables.  So you have this

```
users
   id
 //and other stuff

topics
   id
 //and other stuff

votes 
   user_id
   topic_id
   value (1 or -1)
 //and other stuff, you could put the time for example
```

Then you can do the count for a topic simply

```
SELECT
  sum(value)
FROM
  votes
WHERE
 topic_id = 1
```

Then you simply flip `value` for up or down or delete the record for 0.

You can tell if a user voted on a question and how

```
SELECT
   value
FROM
   votes
WHERE
   topic_id = 1 --current topic
 AND
   user_id = 20 --current user
```

For the user you will get `no record` or `-1` or `1`. Then it's trivial to set the state of the buttons.

You can't force the data into a model that it doesn't fit. The data dictates the relationships that it needs.  When you find the right one you know because everything becomes trivial to do.

One last thing you should make the `votes` have a combined unique key on `user_id` and `topic_id`.  That way a user can not vote 2x on the same topic

```
topic_id, user_id
   1       1   //ok
   1       2   //ok
   2       1   //ok
//   1       1 - this violates the unique constraint
```

If you don't know how to do that, in PHPmyAdmin, in the structure tab, check the checkbox next to each field, then below there is some buttons one says unique, just click it.  (not the one on the rows, but below there). It can even be the Primary key, however there is an argument for a separate surrogate key (auto increment id)

Comment: You can't make the answer better after I've already upvoted it!

Comment: Sorry, I always make like 50 million edits.  Curse of dyslexia, I think backwards.

Comment: Sure, I hope it makes sense.  I was trying to say in the comments not to waste your time because without the right relationships nothing else works correctly.